# Способы чтения xml файла

Tags: c#, xml

Какие способы чтения xml файла существуют в C#, кроме `XmlDocument`, `XmlDocumentXPatch` и `XmlReader` ?

update: Мне нужен способ чтения от элемента к элементу, и допустим вывод их на консоль, при этом xml большие, поэтому первые два способа использовать нельзя.

update2: вот что получилось набросать, проблема в генерации полноценного запроса `Insert`, учитывая вложенность, сейчас просто для примера добавляется 1 элемент

```
while (xml.Read())
    {
       if (xml.NodeType.ToString() == "Element")
             {                
                if (xml.IsEmptyElement != true)
                    {
                        myStack.Push(xml.Name);
                    }
              }
        else if (xml.NodeType.ToString() == "Text")
              {
                string first = myStack.Peek().ToString();
                myStack.Pop();
                string second = myStack.Peek().ToString();
                myStack.Push(first);
                string cmd = "INSERT INTO " + second + " (" + first + ") VALUES ('" + xml.Value + "')";
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmd, conn);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
               }
        else if (xml.NodeType.ToString() == "EndElement")
               {                    
                    myStack.Pop();
               }
    }
```

Comment: @Regent обновил вопрос

Comment: XMLReader - Represents a reader that provides fast, noncached, forward-only access to XML data. Разве это не решает проблему?

Comment: первые два способа вас не устраивают. третий устраивает. в чем суть вопроса? пользуйтесь `XmlReader`.

Comment: Есть ещё `XDocument`, но он тоже по идее грузит всё дерево в память. Пользуйтесь `XmlReader`'ом.

Comment: @PashaPash мне нужно знать "родителя" у элемента, даже точнее 2 предыдущих и если следующий узел `Text`, то формировать запрос в бд, но много нюансов, поэтому ищу что то другое, но походу нет

Comment: ну вычитывайте по одному, запоминайте 2 предыдущих и проверяйте текущий. ни один способ не даст вам читать быстро, но при этом нелинейно.

Comment: @PashaPash Если вложенность большая? Или как вариант я попал на список из "равноправных" элементов со значениями

Comment: никто ж не знает что именно там у вас происходит. приведите пример xml. покажите код, которым пробовали решить проблему. перечислите нюансы. но что-то мне подсказывает что вопрос будет слишком объемным. ну или решайте проблему самостоятельно - пишите код поверх XmlReader, тесты на него и заставляйте их проходить, рефаторя код в процессе.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Способы чтения xml, существующие в .NET:

- XmlReader
- XmlDocument
- XPathDocument
- XDocument/XElement
- XmlSerializer
- DataContractSerializer / SoapFormatter
- DataSet.ReadXml / DataTable.ReadXml

Последние два пункта только для документов определённой структуры, не произвольной. Добавил их для полноты картины.

Если файлы большие, то подходит только первый способ.
Если не хочется вручную возиться с запоминанием родителей в переменных, то можно применить следующий подход: считываем регулярно повторяющиеся поддеревья в XElement (или другой класс по нраву). Но это применимо только для файлов с повторяющейся структурой.

Допустим, имеется следующий файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<persons>
  <person>
    <name>Vasya</name>
    <address>
      <planet>Mars</planet>
      <city>New Vasyuki</city>
    </address>
  </person>

  <person>
    <name>Petya</name>
    <address>
      <planet>Earth</planet>
      <city>Urupinsk</city>
    </address>
  </person>
</persons>
```

Предполагается, что узлов person много. Таким образом, в память загружается лишь одно такое поддерево за раз.

```
using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("file.xml"))
{
    while (xmlReader.Read())
    {
        if (xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("person"))
        {
            XmlReader personSubtree = xmlReader.ReadSubtree();
            XElement personElement = XElement.Load(personSubtree);
            // здесь обрабатываем personElement
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Это замечательное решение, но проблема именно в том что есть "заголовки" например кто отправил и тд, а потом только идет циклическая часть, и никак не могу понять как распарсить учитывая вложенность и прочее. Подробнее в обсуждении под вопросом, чтоб не дублировать информацию

Comment: А какие ограничения на структуру для последних двух пунктов? Не могли бы вы объяснить подробнее?

Comment: @e1s DataContractSerializer по умолчанию не работает с атрибутами xml. SoapFormatter предназначен для SOAP-конвертов. DataSet и DataTable сохраняют/читают данные в табличном формате.

Comment: @e1s: Всё равно не вижу проблемы. Считывайте заголовки отдельно, а потом циклическую часть в цикле. Покажите лучше примерный XML, чтобы была понятна структура.

Comment: Проблема в том что я не знаю заранее какая xml

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov обновил вопрос