# Как парсить xml?

Tags: c#, xml

Подскажите. Всё что я имею это:

```
public Form1()
{
     InitializeComponent();
}

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void XML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

xml такой

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<graph>
    <title>Dijkstra</title> 
    <points>
        <point id="1" y="3" x="1"/>
    </points>
    <lines>
        <line id="1" weight="10" to="2" from="1"/>
    </lines>
</graph>
```

Comment: Пример xml файла покажите.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<graph>
<title>Dijkstra</title>
<points>
<point id="1" y="3" x="1"/>
</points>
<lines>
<line id="1" weight="10" to="2" from="1"/>
</lines>
</graph>

Comment: И что у вас не получилось? Литературу хоть какую-нибудь читали? Документацию? XML-ка так-то тривиальная.

Comment: В основном я читал msdn про парсинг на консоль. И потом решил попробовать сделать через WinForms и сижу голову ломаю

Comment: Выполните сначала сами что-нибудь. а так вопрос следует закрыть. Мы не бюро по написанию кода

Comment: Ну так парсят в *структуру классов*, а не в консоль. Потом эта структура классов может использоваться хоть в консольном приложении, хоть в WinForms, хоть в веб.

Comment: Поддерживаю предыдущего оратора. Разбор XML конвертирует XML в набор объектов, и не зависит от того, какой тип приложения у вас.

Comment: [Способы чтения xml](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431811/184217)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для такого файла

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<graph>
<title>Dijkstra</title> 
<points>
    <point id="1" y="3" x="1"/>
    <point id="2" y="30" x="10"/>
    <point id="3" y="300" x="100"/>
</points>
<lines>
    <line id="1" weight="10" to="2" from="1"/>
    <line id="2" weight="100" to="20" from="10"/>
    <line id="3" weight="1000" to="200" from="100"/>
</lines>
```

получилось так

[image: Пример работы]

Идем [сюда](http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/) и получаем такой набор классов

```
namespace WinFormsAppXmlParse
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "point")]
    public class Point
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "y")]
        public string Y { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "x")]
        public string X { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "points")]
    public class Points
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "point")]
        public List<Point> Point { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "line")]
    public class Line
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "weight")]
        public string Weight { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "to")]
        public string To { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "from")]
        public string From { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "lines")]
    public class Lines
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "line")]
        public List<Line> Line { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "graph")]
    public class Graph
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "points")]
        public Points Points { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "lines")]
        public Lines Lines { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Будем работать в духе `MVP`, вот интерфейс и кодбихайнд формы, который она реализует

```
public interface IMainForm
{
    string Output { get; set; }

    event EventHandler<string> SelectedFile;
    event EventHandler<string> SelectedNode;
}

public partial class MainForm : Form, IMainForm
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Output
    {
        get => textBoxOutput.Text;
        set => textBoxOutput.Text = value;
    }

    //событие выбора файла
    public event EventHandler<string> SelectedFile;
    //событие выбора в listbox
    public event EventHandler<string> SelectedNode;

    //выбор файла
    private void buttonSelectFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        System.IO.FileInfo example = new System.IO.FileInfo("file.xml");

        openFileDialog.CheckFileExists = true;
        openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer);
        openFileDialog.Filter = string.Format("{0} файлы ({1})|*{1}|Все файлы (*.*)|*.*",
                                example.Extension.Substring(1).ToUpper(),
                                example.Extension);

        var result = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBoxFile.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
            textBoxOutput.Text = String.Empty;
            //вызываем событие выбора файла
            SelectedFile?.Invoke(this, openFileDialog.FileName);
        }
        else
        {
            textBoxFile.Text = String.Empty;
            textBoxOutput.Text = String.Empty;
        }
    }

    //выбор раздела
    private void listBoxSelectNode_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var item = listBoxSelectNode.SelectedItem.ToString();

        //вызываем событие выбора в listbox
        SelectedNode?.Invoke(this, item);
    }
}
```

Вот класс `Presenter`а, в котором поработаем с xml

```
public class Presenter
{
    private readonly IMainForm _mainForm;
    private Graph _graph;

    //ctor
    public Presenter(IMainForm mainForm)
    {
        _mainForm = mainForm ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mainForm));

        _mainForm.SelectedFile += _mainForm_SelectedFile;
        _mainForm.SelectedNode += _mainForm_SelectedNode;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Выбран файл
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void _mainForm_SelectedFile(object sender, string file)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(file)) throw new ArgumentNullException(file);

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Graph));

        // читаем файл и десериализуем
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            _graph = (Graph)serializer.Deserialize(sr);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Выбрана нода
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="item"></param>
    private void _mainForm_SelectedNode(object sender, string item)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(item)) throw new ArgumentNullException(item);
        if (_graph == null) return;

        switch (item)
        {
            case "title":
                _mainForm.Output = _graph.Title;
            break;
            case "points":
                _mainForm.Output = ShowPoints(_graph.Points);
                break;
            case "lines":
                _mainForm.Output = ShowLines(_graph.Lines);
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException(nameof(item));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Формирование вывода Точек
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="points"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private string ShowPoints(Points points)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var point in points.Point)
        {
            var str = $"Точка:{point.Id} - X:{point.X}, Y:{point.Y}";
            sb.AppendLine(str);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Формирование вывода Линий
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="lines"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private string ShowLines(Lines lines)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var line in lines.Line)
        {
            var str = $"Линия:{line.Id} - начало:{line.From}, конец:{line.To}, толщина:{line.Weight}";
            sb.AppendLine(str);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

`Presenter` и `View`(форму) свяжем между собой в `Program.cs` так

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    MainForm form = new MainForm();
    Presenter presenter = new Presenter(form);

    Application.Run(form);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, огромное, выручили прям на 100%

Comment: можно ссылку на архив с вашей работой ?

Comment: @KonstantinVoskov, [здесь](https://yadi.sk/d/A58PQp4w3VNvHz) пожалуйста.