# Трансформация xsd средствами C#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Возможно ли используя C# преобразовать/трансформировать xsd файл к промежуточному виду? Под промежуточным видом имеется ввиду например удаление из схемы каких-то паттернов (повторяющихся структур), для того чтобы исходная схема соответствовала новому описанию

Comment: xsd - это обычный xml. В C# (вернее, в .NET) богатые средства для работы с xml. Поэтому краткий ответ: да, можно. Как именно - зависит от исходных данных и желаемого результата.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov например мне нужно во всем xml заменить один патерн на другой

Comment: Всё стандартно, как при работе с любым другим типом файлов: открываем xml, находим нужные данные, заменяем/удаляем их, сохраняем xml. \ Способы чтения xml, существующие в .NET: [тыц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431811/184217)